# Catch TField Validate exception In Delphi Form

Tags: delphi, exception, field

I am using a DataModule that contains some TFDQuery and some of the fields have validation that fires an error of a custom Exception Type (EInvalidFieldValueException) on OnValidate event. This type returns a TField so that a form that is consuming it can capture the field and can determine which component (DBWare) should display a balloon (not a standard MessageBox) to be more intuitive to the user. **The problem is that I do not know how to catch and supress the default message box exception for the form to be able to display the balloon instead of a standard message**. Could anyone give a tip?
*Note: it is possible that more than one instance of this form is open (of course with its respective DataModule instance)*

Comment: So, you raise an exception in field's `OnValidate` event handler and now you want to notify a data aware control linked to the field's dataset of an active form for displaying balloon hint? Is that what you want?

Comment: The *exact moment of the error* is when `OnValidate` is fired, and the earliest you can catch it is the beginning of that procedure. I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: @Victoria Yes, you understood exactly the point. May you help me?

Comment: @KenWhite The "exact moment" I am referring to is because the DBWare control (like a DBEdit) only puts its value on exit, which triggers the validate of this. But since there are several types of DBWare controls, I do not know how to capture all of them and determine if the error is of the type created by me to proceed as intended in the above question.

Comment: Then [edit] your question and make it clear what you're asking. We shouldn't have to be guessing or playing 20 questions to find out. You may want to ask DBWare (I'm not familiar with those controls). I've never had an issue with `OnValidate` and standard DB-aware Delphi controls.

Comment: @KenWhite I edited the question and tried to clarify it for a better understanding. tks

Comment: Hm, that will be difficult. One possible way around could be handling `TApplicationEvents.OnException` event and iterate there dataset's (private) `FDataSources`, for each data source iterate (protected) `DataLinks` and for each (`TFieldDataLink`) data link check if its `Field` property matches the one served by the exception object. If so, then you can check if this data link's `Control` is hosted by the active form. If so, then you can show the balloon. In other words, globally catch your exception and find a control linked to the _invalid_ field. What to do if there's more controls linked?